# Python: Dictionary that only retains last n inserted keys

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I'm planning to read millions of small files from disk. To minimize i/o, I planned to use a dictionary that maps a file path to its content. I only want the dictionary to retain the last n keys inserted into it, though (so the dictionary will act as a cache).

Is there a data structure in Python that already implements this behavior? I wanted to check before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If you want to close this can you please leave a note saying why?

Comment: Looks a lot like a LRU cache. You might want to dig into the internals of [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to see how it's implemented there.

Comment: Wow thanks @PatrickHaugh the lru_cache looks awesome. It may be the solution I'm after. Digging a bit deeper...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my particular problem, since I needed to read files from disk, I think I'll use the lru cache as @PatrickHaugh suggested. Here's one way to use the cache:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=10)
def read_file(file_path):
  print(' * reading', file_path)
  return file_path # update to return the read file

for i in range(100):
  if i % 2 == 0:
    i = 0 # test that requests for 0 don't require additional i/o
  print(' * value of', i, 'is', read_file(i))
```

The output shows that requests for 0 do not incur additional i/o, which is perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Use `collections.deque` for this with a maxlen of 6, so that it stores only the last 6 elements and store the information as key value pairs

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(maxlen=6)
d.extend([(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4), (5,5), (6,6)])
d
# deque([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6)], maxlen=6)
d.extend([(7,7)])
d
# deque([(2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7)], maxlen=6)
```

Comment: How will `deque` help with holding mappings like a dictionary? Have I misread the question?

Comment: You can store anything in a deque, just like a list and I am suggesting to store a mapping (key, value pairs) as each element

Comment: Got it, with a cost, i.e. loss of O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and its method `popitem` to ensure you keep only the last *n* keys added to the dictionary. Specifying `last=False` with `popitem` ensures the behaviour is "FIFO", i.e. First-In, First-Out. Here's a trivial example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

n = 3
d = OrderedDict()

for i in range(5):
    if len(d) == n:
        removed = d.popitem(last=False)
        print(f'Item removed: {removed}')
    d[i] = i+1

print(d)

Item removed: (0, 1)
Item removed: (1, 2)
OrderedDict([(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)])
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp! So `last=False` will pop from the start of the keys list (ordered by time of insertion)? If so, this is perfect.

Comment: @duhaime, Yes, that's exactly what it does. `OrderedDict` is ordered by insertion.